# Include javascript menu with active class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to include [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ov5o7q/1/) menu to my web page with following index page code:

```html
<div id="header"><?php include "shared/header.php"; ?></div>        
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu"><?php include "shared/menu.php"; ?></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><?php include "shared/footer.php"; ?></div>
```

And my submenu items have links like: 
`index.php?page=page_something&id=1`.

As you can see in the jsfiddle code, active menu style is different than the inactive ones. So there is no problem. But when I using this code in my web page, this does not work.

When I click a menu and load a new page, active menu style is gone and it turns to initial style. So users can't figure out which page they are visiting right now. I hope I could explain my problem.

Comment: I'm sure it's silly but I have to ask, are you importing the same jQuery/Accordion plugin versions inside your project than the ones of the example you provided?

Comment: I import same code in jsfiddle example. Just different style.
And plugin versions same as demo of menu:
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me as I'm not familiar with PHP, but if you are loading a *completely new page* each time, then the accordion is going to reset to whatever the JS is that you have on that page.

Unless you are altering only part of the page, hard-coding default accordion settings on each page, or somehow storing session variables on the browser and consuming them via JS, then there's no way for the accordion to keep its state as you navigate across pages.

**EDIT:** I see you are passing some parameters in your query string. But I don't see in your JS where you are parsing them in your page/accordion initialization.

Answer (score 0):

try someting like this :

```
<div id="header"><?php include "shared/header.php"; ?></div>        
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu"><?php include "shared/menu.php"; ?></div>
    <div id="content">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        include 'shared/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><?php include "shared/footer.php"; ?></div>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: In the content section, I just have an embedded youtube iframe video container. And according to selected menu, it loads different playlists to video player and play it. So there is no php file that include to the content section.